# Apache .htaccess RewriteCond to exclude maintenance file and zend backoffice

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have to put a website in maintenance during a big data import.
Import is done in the backoffice, so I need to put the frontoffice in maintenance but not the backoffice

Have have that in my .htaccess that work for all, but I need to exclude all url starting with /admin(.*) :

```
# Maintenance things
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/maintenance.php$
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]

# Standard zend framework rewrite rules :
RewriteRule .* - [env=not_alias:true]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:not_alias} !=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I tried different things that does not work like theses for the first RewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin(.*)|maintenance.php)
```

Or that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/maintenance.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin(.*)$
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No needs of RewriteCond just à good RewriteRule :

```
# Maintenance things
RewriteRule !^(admin(.*)|index.php|maintenance.php)$ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]

# Standard zend framework rewrite rules :
RewriteRule .* - [env=not_alias:true]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:not_alias} !=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it could be done with .htaccess but there is another option with controller plugin you could try.
You can put your logic in dispatchLoopStartup() hook and if it is a request to the frontoffice then redirect the user to maintenance.php otherwise do nothing.

Comment: I need to do it in the .htaccess to do not have to use memory with Zend / Php and MySQL access during my data import.